# taking text file into hive database

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-serde

i trying to run this code for so long time can somebody tell me what is problem in it
code :-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE samp_log 
(
ip String ,col1 String ,col2 String , date String , time_hour int ,time_min int 
,time_sec int ,zone int , request String , request_con String , resp_code int 
,resp_byte BIGINT , reference String , ext_reference String , col13 String 
,col14 String ,col15 String , col16 String ,col17 String  
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"=" ,[,]") 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

> error - Driver returned: 1.  Errors: OK FAILED: Execution Error,
>   return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot
>   validate serde:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe

i also added jar file of hive-contrib..

Comment: What is the version of Hive?

Comment: hive-hcatalog 0.13.0

Comment: `MultiDelimitSerde` is available only from Hive-0.14.0.

Comment: so any other way to run it?

Comment: Please post some sample dataset. Hive-0.13.0 is old and Upgrade would be the best solution.

Comment: sample data is some server log file like:123.123.123.123 - - [26/Apr/2000:00:23:48 -0400] "GET /pics/wpaper.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 6248 "http://www.cloudera.com/" "Mozilla/4.05 (Macintosh; I; PPC)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use RegexSerDe

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-ApacheWeblogData

Here is a POC:

```
create external table mytable  
( 
    ip      string
   ,dt      string
   ,tm      string
   ,tz      string
)
    row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    with serdeproperties  
    (
        'input.regex' = '^(.*?) - - \\[(.*?):(.*?) (.*?)\\].*$'
    )
    location '/tmp/mytable'
;
```

---

```
select * from mytable
;
```

---

```
+-----------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|   mytable.ip    | mytable.dt  | mytable.tm | mytable.tz |
+-----------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 123.123.123.123 | 26/Apr/2000 | 00:23:48   |      -0400 |
+-----------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Hey After running this above commnad it gives output as you shown but it giving error for other command like    Select ip,dt from mytable etc..

Comment: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:

Comment: You'll have to check the logs for more informative error message

Comment: in logs i can't able to understand much it also giving eroor like ( ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask )  i was thinking may be  it will happen by using regex code . It don't give these error if i use basic delimiter command

Comment: P.s. This doesn't seem related to the original post. Do other queries on different tables works?

Comment: Yes it works on different table . Please can you try it to run on your pc because i can't able to find what's wrong in it?   USE somemore data 123.123.123.123 - - [26/Apr/2000:00:23:48 -0400] "GET /pics/5star2000.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 4005 "http://www.jafsoft.com/asctortf/" "Mozilla/4.05 (Macintosh; I; PPC)"
123.123.123.123 - - [26/Apr/2000:00:23:50 -0400] "GET /pics/5star.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1031 "http://www.acadgild.com/" "Mozilla/4.05 (Macintosh; I; PPC)"
123.123.123.123 - - [26/Apr/2000:00:23:51 -0400] "GET /pics/a2hlogo.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 4282 "http://www.acadgild.com/"

Comment: Tested, no issues on my side.

Comment: I wonder why you have to add it in the first place and in any case, this does not seem to be the right place. Please read https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1719